# How do I make my query return one another property inside dictionary

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Below query returns ItemNo's of children and grandchildren in an array of dictionaries, so that relationship is maintained.

```
    public async Task<List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>> GetChild(string parentItemNo)
    {
               var childDetails = await DbContext.Items
                    .Where(x => x.ItemNo== parentItemNo)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(c => new
                    {
                        c.ItemNo, // I can select c.ItemName as well
                        // how do I select ItemName below, tried Select(gc => new { gc.ItemNo, gc.ItemName})
                        GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.Select(gc => gc.ItemNo)  
                    })).ToListAsync();

                var dictionary = childDetails.ToDictionary(d => d.ItemNo, d => d.GrandChildItemNos).ToList();  // how do i set ItemName here

                return dictionary;
       
    }
```

Query returns children(key) and grandchild(value), like below

```
 [{"Key":"A","Value":["AQ11", AH45]},{"Key":"C","Value":["CN22", "CL33", "CG24"]}]
```

how do I to return 'ItemName' as well for each children and grandchildren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
public async Task<List<Child>> GetChild(string parentItemNo)
{
               return await DbContext.Items
                    .Where(x => x.ItemNo== parentItemNo)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(c => new Child
                        {
                            ItemNo = c.ItemNo,
                            ItemName = c.ItemName,
                            GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.Select(gc => 
                               new GrandChild 
                               { 
                                  ItemNo = gc.ItemNo, 
                                  ItemName = gc.ItemName 
                               })  
                        })).ToListAsync();
       
 }
```

Using this class

```
public class GrandChild
{
    public string ItemNo {get;set;}
    public strng ItemName {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public string ItemNo {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<GrandChild> GrandChildItemNos {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done that. But how do I return(ItemName) in the last line.

Comment: the values in the dictionary should now contain both ItemNo and ItemName. So I dont think you need any other changes.

Comment: The variable dictionary has "List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<'a>>>" which does not match my return type "List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>". Since I am sending two strings (itemNo, ItemName) as value  now, may I know what would be the appropriate return type.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to fix your problem.

Comment: Does changes to model as above, affect the existing table ? Since its being used by another application as well, cannot make changes to model if it will affect current table structure.

Comment: It effects the consumer of the function.

Comment: So it affects only the consumer of the function, not the table. Thanks. It works perfect. But returns only the ItemName of grandchildren and not children. May I know do I return 'Children' ItemName as well.

Comment: var dictionary = childDetails.ToDictionary(d => d.ItemNo, d => d.ItemName, d => d.GrandChildSerialNos).ToList();  // says cannot convert lambda func to type 'IEqualityComparer<string>' bcoz its not delegate type

Comment: @Sarahrb "how do I to return 'ItemName' as well for each children and grandchildren" What exactly do you want returned? Could a `KeyValuePair` look like this? `{"Key":"A: NameOfA","Value":["AQ11: NameOfAQ11", AH45: NameOfAH45]}`?

Comment: Just figured. changing my return type to list<child> helped. Thanks a lot.